# Does 95.8% silver tarnish as fast 92.5% silver?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, metal, silver

I've been trying to find out whether 95.8% (Britannia silver) would tarnish as fast as 92.5% (Sterling silver)? I haven't been able to find much on tarnish for Britannia silver.

Given that both silvers are kept in the exact same environment, would the Britannia silver tarnish at the same rate as Sterling silver? If not which of the two tarnishes quicker?

Comment: I suspect they are the same; However, I think the only way to know is to test or find a reference .  For example ; adding  0. 3 % Cu to steel makes a measurable increase in atmospheric corrosion resistance , which I doubt could have been deduced .

Answer (score 1):

If you look here: https://blog.centimegift.com/does-sterling-silver-tarnish/, it says that pure silver is very tarnish resistant. Sterling silver on the other hand being mixed with some Cu to enchance the metal's mechanical properties tarnishes as a result of the Cu in it. Therefore, considering that the amount of Cu in Britannia silver is smaller, it should tarnish more slowly than sterling silver. In practice i dont know if there will be a significant difference as the increse in silver purity is not that much.